# How do I change color of the pgftext in a declared pgfshape without changing the shape color?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-styles

How do I make it so that only the pgftext of the declared shape has different color without the shape itself?

Below is what I want and the code (currently I have black text for the middle box).

[image: 3 boxes]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%--------------------------------------------------------
% Packages
%--------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{AlegreyaSans}
\usepackage{bm}                 % bold math symbols
\usepackage{xcolor}

%--------------------------------------------------------
% Shapes
%--------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{shape1}{
  \savedanchor\northeast{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfshapeminwidth}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfshapeminheight}%
    \pgf@x=0.5\pgf@x
    \pgf@y=0.5\pgf@y
  }
  % This is redundant, but makes some things easier:
  \savedanchor\southwest{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfshapeminwidth}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfshapeminheight}%
    \pgf@x=-0.5\pgf@x
    \pgf@y=-0.5\pgf@y
  }
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]

  % Define same anchor a normal rectangle has
  \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
  \anchor{north}{\northeast \pgf@x=0pt}
  \anchor{east}{\northeast \pgf@y=0pt}
  \anchor{south}{\southwest \pgf@x=0pt}
  \anchor{west}{\southwest \pgf@y=0pt}
  \anchor{north east}{\northeast}
  \anchor{north west}{\northeast \pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
  \anchor{south west}{\southwest}
  \anchor{south east}{\southwest \pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
  \anchor{text}{
    \pgfpointorigin
    \advance\pgf@x by -.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by -.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by +.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
  }

  %Port Anchors
  \anchor{A}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \pgf@x=-1\pgf@x%
    \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y%
  }

  \anchor{B}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \pgf@x=-1\pgf@x%
    \pgf@y=-.5\pgf@y%
  }

  % Draw the Rectangle box and the port labels
  \backgroundpath{
    % Rectangle box
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\southwest}{\northeast}

    % Draw port labels
    \begingroup
    \tikzset{mystyle/port labels} % Use font from this style
    \tikz@textfont

    \csname pgf@anchor@shape1@A\endcsname %
    \pgftext[left,at={\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}},x=\pgfshapeinnerxsep]{A}

    \csname pgf@anchor@shape1@B\endcsname %
    \pgftext[left,at={\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}},x=\pgfshapeinnerxsep]{B}

    \endgroup
  }
}
\makeatother

%--------------------------------------------------------
% Shape configuration
%--------------------------------------------------------

% Key to add font macros to the current font
\tikzset{add font/.code={\expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@textfont\expandafter{\tikz@textfont#1}}} 

% % Define default style for this node
\tikzset{mystyle/port labels/.style={font=\small,text=blue}}

\tikzset{every shape1 node/.style={draw,minimum width=2.5cm,minimum height=2cm,very thick,inner sep=1mm,outer sep=0mm,cap=round}}

%--------------------------------------------------------
% Begin Document
%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[shape=shape1] (p1) at (0,0) {};
  \node[shape=shape1] (p2) at (0,3) {};
  \node[shape=shape1] (p3) at (0,6) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not understand the question but the text color text gets stored in `\tikz@textcolor`, so you could just use it.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%--------------------------------------------------------
% Packages
%--------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{AlegreyaSans}
\usepackage{bm}                 % bold math symbols
\usepackage{xcolor}

%--------------------------------------------------------
% Shapes
%--------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{shape1}{
  \savedanchor\northeast{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfshapeminwidth}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfshapeminheight}%
    \pgf@x=0.5\pgf@x
    \pgf@y=0.5\pgf@y
  }
  % This is redundant, but makes some things easier:
  \savedanchor\southwest{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfshapeminwidth}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfshapeminheight}%
    \pgf@x=-0.5\pgf@x
    \pgf@y=-0.5\pgf@y
  }
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]

  % Define same anchor a normal rectangle has
  \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
  \anchor{north}{\northeast \pgf@x=0pt}
  \anchor{east}{\northeast \pgf@y=0pt}
  \anchor{south}{\southwest \pgf@x=0pt}
  \anchor{west}{\southwest \pgf@y=0pt}
  \anchor{north east}{\northeast}
  \anchor{north west}{\northeast \pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
  \anchor{south west}{\southwest}
  \anchor{south east}{\southwest \pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
  \anchor{text}{
    \pgfpointorigin
    \advance\pgf@x by -.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by -.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by +.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
  }

  %Port Anchors
  \anchor{A}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \pgf@x=-1\pgf@x%
    \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y%
  }

  \anchor{B}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \pgf@x=-1\pgf@x%
    \pgf@y=-.5\pgf@y%
  }

  % Draw the Rectangle box and the port labels
  \backgroundpath{
    % Rectangle box
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\southwest}{\northeast}

    % Draw port labels
    \begingroup
    \tikzset{mystyle/port labels} % Use font from this style

    \csname pgf@anchor@shape1@A\endcsname %
    \pgftext[left,at={\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}},x=\pgfshapeinnerxsep]{%
        \textcolor{\tikz@textcolor}{\tikz@textfont A}}

    \csname pgf@anchor@shape1@B\endcsname %
    \pgftext[left,at={\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}},x=\pgfshapeinnerxsep]{%
        \textcolor{\tikz@textcolor}{\tikz@textfont B}}

    \endgroup
  }
}
\makeatother

%--------------------------------------------------------
% Shape configuration
%--------------------------------------------------------

% Key to add font macros to the current font
\tikzset{add font/.code={\expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@textfont\expandafter{\tikz@textfont#1}}} 

% % Define default style for this node
\tikzset{mystyle/port labels/.style={font=\small,text=blue}}

\tikzset{every shape1 node/.style={draw,minimum width=2.5cm,minimum height=2cm,very thick,inner sep=1mm,outer sep=0mm,cap=round}}

%--------------------------------------------------------
% Begin Document
%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[shape=shape1] (p1) at (0,0) {};
  \node[shape=shape1] (p2) at (0,3) {};
  \node[shape=shape1] (p3) at (0,6) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll mark this as correct answer because it does what I need but you'll have to tikzset mystyle/port labels's style twice to have the middle one with different color. I'll post what I ended up doing as another answer which is more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

This defines a new key "pin color" that can be passed as a style.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%--------------------------------------------------------
% Packages
%--------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{AlegreyaSans}
\usepackage{bm}                 % bold math symbols
\usepackage{xcolor}

%--------------------------------------------------------
% Shapes
%--------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter

%define new keys
\pgfkeys{/tikz/pin font/.store in=\pinfont}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/pin color/.store in=\pincolor}

\pgfdeclareshape{shape1}{
  \savedanchor\northeast{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfshapeminwidth}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfshapeminheight}%
    \pgf@x=0.5\pgf@x
    \pgf@y=0.5\pgf@y
  }
  % This is redundant, but makes some things easier:
  \savedanchor\southwest{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfshapeminwidth}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfshapeminheight}%
    \pgf@x=-0.5\pgf@x
    \pgf@y=-0.5\pgf@y
  }
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]

  % Define same anchor a normal rectangle has
  \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
  \anchor{north}{\northeast \pgf@x=0pt}
  \anchor{east}{\northeast \pgf@y=0pt}
  \anchor{south}{\southwest \pgf@x=0pt}
  \anchor{west}{\southwest \pgf@y=0pt}
  \anchor{north east}{\northeast}
  \anchor{north west}{\northeast \pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
  \anchor{south west}{\southwest}
  \anchor{south east}{\southwest \pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
  \anchor{text}{
    \pgfpointorigin
    \advance\pgf@x by -.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by -.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by +.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
  }

  %Port Anchors
  \anchor{A}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \pgf@x=-1\pgf@x%
    \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y%
  }

  \anchor{B}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \pgf@x=-1\pgf@x%
    \pgf@y=-.5\pgf@y%
  }

  % Draw the Rectangle box and the port labels
  \backgroundpath{
    % Rectangle box
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\southwest}{\northeast}

    % Draw port labels
    \begingroup
    \ifdefined\pinfont\pinfont\fi
    \ifdefined\pincolor\color{\pincolor}\fi


    \csname pgf@anchor@shape1@A\endcsname %
    \pgftext[left,at={\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}},x=\pgfshapeinnerxsep]{A}

    \csname pgf@anchor@shape1@B\endcsname %
    \pgftext[left,at={\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}},x=\pgfshapeinnerxsep]{B}

    \endgroup
  }
}
\makeatother

%--------------------------------------------------------
% Shape configuration
%--------------------------------------------------------

\tikzset{every shape1 node/.style={draw,minimum width=2.5cm,minimum height=2cm,pin font=\small,very thick,inner sep=1mm,outer sep=0mm,cap=round}}

%--------------------------------------------------------
% Begin Document
%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[shape=shape1] (p1) at (0,0) {};
  \node[shape=shape1,pin color=blue] (p2) at (0,3) {};
  \node[shape=shape1] (p3) at (0,6) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```